# Why the shortcut "Ctrl + Enter" doesn't send my current line to REPL when I program Julia in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, julia, shortcut

I believe I install both Julia and VS code correctly but this shortcut with a bunch of other ones just don't work. Do I miss anything here? When I press ctrl + enter, nothing happens in my repl. I am just wondering why this built-in shortcut doesn't work

Comment: Did you try alt-enter?

Comment: Yep. Nothing happened...

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Julia extension for VS code? If yes, you can also check available shortcuts under the Settings icon, there is "Keyboard shortcuts," so check there if you are using the right set of shortcuts.

Regards,
Honza

Comment: Yep, I did. The keyboard shortcuts show ctrl+enter as sending my line to repl but it just doesn’t work

Comment: I am not sure. I do have my repl open. Is there anything I need to do?

Comment: Ah, I just figured it out. You have to save your new file as .jl before this shortwork can work.

Answer (score -1):

Ah, I just figured it out. You have to save your new file as .jl before this shortwork can work.

Comment: You do _not_ need to save the file, it is enough to set Language Mode to 'Julia'. Go to the lower right of the status bar, where it says 'Plain text' by default, and click on that.